# How to filter queryset in Django Admin to display only one entry?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've got such function in my MessageAdmin:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user = request.user.id)
    return Message.objects.all().filter(groups__in = [group_obj.id for group_obj in user_profile.group.all()])
```

I want to return all messages that have same group as User has. But with this construction all messages returns twice, if User has more than one group - so I've got error, when I try to open any message.

Edit: UserProfile is extension for User model, where I store all groups with ManyToManyField.

Comment: I think you need: Message.objects.filter(groups__in = [group_obj.id for group_obj in user_profile.group.all()]).distinct()

Comment: Cool. I'll add it as an answer. If you could mark it as accepted, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
Message.objects.filter(groups__in = [group_obj.id for group_obj in \
    user_profile.group.all()]).distinct()
```